# Fast multiplication with a full binary $n \times 2^n$ matrix

Tags: algorithms

Let $A$ a $n\times n$ matrix, and X the full matrix of $n\times 2^n$ binary vectors (you can choose the order of the columns of X).

What is the fastest way to compute the product AX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ were a $1 \times n$ matrix, let $X_n$ denote your matrix for a given value of $n$, and let $A_{<n}$ consist of all but the last entry $A_n$ of $A$. Then up to rearrangement,
$$
AX_n = \begin{bmatrix} A_{<n} X_{n-1} & A_{<n} X_{n-1} + A_n \end{bmatrix},
$$
where $+A_n$ means adding $A_n$ to *all* entries. The running time of this procedure satisfies the recurrence
$$
T(n) = T(n-1) + O(2^{n-1}),
$$
whose solution is $T(n) = O(2^n)$, which is linear in the size of the output. This should be compared to the trivial $O(n2^n)$ solution.

You can save a factor of $n$ in your case in the same way. The resulting algorithm is asymptotically optimal.

Comment: I agree, it is optimal. But what if we get a rectangular matrix let say $m\times n$ , $m>n$, for $A$, I guess using that result we can go to $O(2^n*m*n^(-1))$ but can we do better?

Comment: I don’t follow. There are $2^nm$ outputs. Any algorithm would take at least that much time.